# is there a method to turn general sound on or off in an SFML application?

Tags: c++, sfml

I want to make a button in main.cpp, by pressing which the general sound will turn on or off, but I have sounds scattered over each .h and .cpp file.

I created the button itself, but so far it does not entail anything

After reading the documentation about Sound in SFML, I could not find the desired function, etc.

If there is such a function, I would be very happy.

for example:
GameState.h

```
class GameState :
    public State
{
private:
    sf::SoundBuffer soundBufferMiss;
    sf::SoundBuffer soundBufferCrash;
    sf::SoundBuffer soundBufferStartGame;
    sf::SoundBuffer soundBufferWin;
    sf::SoundBuffer soundBufferLose;

    sf::Sound soundMiss;
    sf::Sound soundCrash;
    sf::Sound soundStartGame;
    sf::Sound soundWin;
    sf::Sound soundLose;

    sf::Text textAboutPlayer;
    sf::Text textAboutEnemy;
    sf::Text textInfo;

    Legend legend = Legend(100, 500);

    Map enemyMap = Map(770, 100, 1);
    Map* playerMap;

    bool winFlag;
    bool playerMove;

    std::map<std::string, Button*> buttons;
    std::vector<MapCoord> damagedDecks;
    
public:

    GameState(std::vector<State*>* statesPointer, Map* playerMap = nullptr);
    ~GameState();

    void botAttack(int i, int j);
    bool checkField(int coorI, int coorJ);
    void ArtificInt();
    void update(sf::RenderWindow* targetWindow = nullptr);
    void render(sf::RenderWindow* targetWindow = nullptr);
};
```

for example PlacingState.h

```
    class PlacingState :
    public State
{
private:
    sf::SoundBuffer soundBufferPlacing;
    sf::Sound soundPlacing;
    sf::SoundBuffer soundBufferFlipShip;
    sf::Sound soundFlipShip;

    sf::Text headerText;
    sf::Text helpText;
    sf::Text yourShipsText;

    sf::RectangleShape helpTextBackground;

    Map playerMap = Map(110, 100);

    std::vector<sf::RectangleShape> outMapShipsTable;

    std::map<std::string, Button*> buttons;

    std::vector<OutMapShip> outMapShip;

public:

    PlacingState(std::vector<State*>* statesPointer);
    ~PlacingState();

void initOutMapShips();

void update(sf::RenderWindow* targetWindow = nullptr);
void render(sf::RenderWindow* targetWindow = nullptr);
};
```

Comment: _"but I have sounds scattered over each .h and .cpp file."_ - methinks you should organize your project now before it gets any worse.

Comment: Why not just make a function that changes volume to 0% ?

Comment: Thank you guys for the responsiveness, I'm just starting to figure it all out. I'll try to organize my project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean changing the global volume for all sounds and musics there is this function you can try: [SFML 2.5.1 sf::Listener::setGlobalVolume](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Listener.php#a803a24a1fc04620cacc9f88c6fbc0e3a)

Example (turn off sound):

```
sf::Listener::setGlobalVolume(0.0f);
```